# The meaning of 以外 in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> すぐにそのことに思い至らなかったのが自分でも**以外**だった。

Is he saying that he is surprise by the fact that EVEN to him, not realising this immediately was/is something bad?

> Noun + 以外 : with the exception of; excepting

Is probably the only "以外" that I know..

Can you explain to me how am I suppose to interpret this "以外" ?

> それにしても、ハルカの主張は筋が通らない気がした。

And the second part is "Nevertheless, Haruka's claim, to me, make no sense" 
correct?

thanks!

Comment: Makes no sense; Must be a mistake for 「意外」.

Comment: 意外/以外 is one of the most common spelling errors in Japanese :)

Comment: I see ! I was completely lost, I thought that I was missing something important, haha.
Thanks everyone!